# How to calculate the number of business days between two date columns across multiple holiday calendars quickly in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is there a way to use vector calculations to apply multiple holiday calendars in Pandas depending on the contents in a given column?

In my case, I have currency pairs with a start date and end date, and want to work out how many business days are between the dates for the given currency pair.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have tried multiple approaches now without success.

My data `df` is structured thus:

```
TRADE_DATE  SETTLE_DATE  FROM_CRRNCY  TO_CRRNCY
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   USD          GBP
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   EUR          GBP
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   JPY          GBP
```

From here, I then have a separate dataframe `holidaydates`, which declares all the full holiday days for a given currency that is structured thus:

```
Currency  Date
GBP       01/01/2019
USD       01/01/2019
USD       21/01/2019
```

I would like to get to an output that is similar to below, notice that the USD holiday means that the count of business days is one smaller than for EUR or JPY.

```
TRADE_DATE  SETTLE_DATE  FROM_CRRNCY  TO_CRRNCY  Trade Date - Settle Date
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   USD          GBP        2
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   EUR          GBP        3
18/01/2019  22/01/2019   JPY          GBP        3
```

**The Workaround**

This is my solution that currently works, but is implemented slowly using non-best practice:

To be able to use the holidaydates values later, these are then split into different dataframes called `holidaydatesusd`, `holidaydatesgbp` etc.
This has been implemented manually, although it could be looped if required:

`holidaydatesusd = holidaydates.loc[holidaydates['Currency'] == 'USD','Date'].tolist()`

To be able to determine the number of business days between two values, I have used numpy's `busday_count`, applying the result as a new column in the dataframe. The code for this is shown below, again, this is a very manual implementation:

```
df['Trade Date - Settle Date'] =  df.apply(lambda row: \
   np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydatesusd) \
   if row['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'USD' else \
   np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydatesgbp) \
   if row['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'GBP' else \
   np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydatesjpy) \
   if row['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'JPY' else \
   np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydateseur) \
   if row['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'EUR' else 
   np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE']), axis=1)
```

To get both sides of the calculation, I then repeat the code above, but for the FROM_CRRNCY, before finally taking the minimum of the two returned counts.

**The Vector Solution?**

Although the code above currently getting the correct answer, I am looking for a more Pythonic way to implement the solution.

As the code is resorting to an if...else loop row logic, this forces the function to evaluate each individual row, rather than looking across the entire dataframe.

Instead, is there a way to extract the matching logic from the function and perform that across the entire dataframe in one go, providing the answers that I need, without resorting to row level evaluation?

Any suggestions on how I could also write this to accommodate the hundreds of currency pairs would also be welcome, as I don't want to implement this as it currently stands.

**What I have tried so far...**

So far, I have attempted the following:

```
# Split the dataframe into separate frames with the same currency
df_usd = df.loc[((df['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'USD') | (df['TO_CRRNCY'] == 'USD'))]
df_eur = df.loc[((df['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'EUR') | (df['TO_CRRNCY'] == 'EUR'))]
df_gbp = df.loc[((df['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'GBP') | (df['TO_CRRNCY'] == 'GBP'))]
df_jpy = df.loc[((df['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'JPY') | (df['TO_CRRNCY'] == 'JPY'))]
```

The next part is where I am unable to successfully proceed.

```
# Now attempt to use the Pandas business day range method, calling count after
df.loc[df_usd, 'Trade Date - Settle Date'] = \
df.loc[df_usd, pd.bdate_range(start = df.loc['TRADE_DATE'], end = df.loc['SETTLE_DATE'], holidays=holidaydatesusd).count()]
```

What I think I'm trying to do now is use the `.loc` function to select the partial USD dataframe, creating a new column called `'Trade Date - Settle Date'` and then set that value to be the business day range `.count()` result for the number of business days between Trade Date and Settle Date, using the USD holiday calendar. Instead, I seem to be passing whole objects to a Timestamp and receive the error below.

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [ # (Big list of my dataframe goes here)... Name: TRADE_DATE, dtype: object] of type  to Timestamp

After a few hours of trying different approaches, including getting various datetime64 errors between the datetime64 (day) or (nanosecond) that numpy supports but pandas does not, I have run out of options. I also realise that the dataframe cuts that I am taking will contain the same rows in many instances, so I would have to work out a method to re-apply them back into the dataframe, picking the highest date.

Is there anyone who can please assist in how best to apply business day calculations across multiple calendars? Perhaps my approach is incorrect and this could be achieved far more simply?

**Update**

The holiday codes were imported into the system using the following code

```
# Define the Lookup Date function for speed
def lookup(s, **args):
    dates = {date:pandas.to_datetime(date, dayfirst='True', **args) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.map(dates)

# Read in the Holiday Name Lookup
holidaydates = pd.read_csv(holidaydates_file,
                     dtype={'Currency': str,
                            'Date': str
                            }
                    )
# Convert to dates
holidaydates['Date'] = lookup(holidaydates['Date'])
```

The holiday dates csv file contains two columns, "Currency" and "Date", and has contents similar to the example above.  The holidaydates start as a dataframe shape (1464,2).

This is then run using this code:

```
df['Trade Date - Settle Date'] =  df.apply(lambda row: np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'], \
holidays=holidaydates.Date[holidaydates.Currency.isin([row['TO_CRRNCY'],row['FROM_CRRNCY']])]), axis=1)
```

This results in the following error:

> ValueError: ('Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates', u'occurred at index 0')

The specific row cited in the error is

```
holidays=holidaydates.Date[holidaydates.Currency.isin([row['TO_CRRNCY'],row['FROM_CRRNCY']])]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Do these holidays have some order or priority? What holidays should be effective when you have for example from `USD` to `GBP`? From your first example the `USD` holidays would take precedence but from your second one it looks the other way round. Shouldn't both be effective?

Comment: Good question. In this instance it would be the "worst" of the holiday calendars, ie if either day was identified as a holiday. My current implementation is to work out the answer for each currency and then use a minimum value between them, but the query is more about how to apply a flexible holiday calendar based upon dataframe row level information. Thanks for looking at the query.

Comment: So am I right to assume that the holiday calendars for both currencies apply? Anyway why not just use something like `df.apply(lambda row: np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydates.Date[holidaydates.Currency.isin([row['FROM_CRRNCY'], row['TO_CRRNCY']])]))` instead of all the explicit `if / else` statements in the `apply` function?

Comment: Will that provide any performance gains? My thought was that by having explicit if /else, the performance would be slightly faster? Currently my dataset is over 16 million rows, and this is giving a considerable performance hit so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: No, performance-wise probably no improvement. You could still use a dict with all the holidays per currency together with `apply`. As for your second example you should either store the *mask* for each currency (i.e. the `df_usd` without the `df.loc`) or not use the masked data frame as an index later on. I.e. you could use `df_usd['Trade Date - Settle Date'] = pd.bdate_range(start=df_usd['TRADE_DATE'], end=df_usd['SETTLE_DATE'], holidays=holidaydatesusd).count()]`. Or you use it own the original `df` but then with `.loc[(df['FROM_CRRNCY'] == 'USD') | (df['TO_CRRNCY'] == 'USD')]`.

Comment: After some testing on the lambda function, I keep on coming up with an error:  ```KeyError: (('TO_CRRNCY', 'FROM_CRRNCY'), u'occurred at index 0')```  Do you have any ideas where I may have gone wrong? The line now looks like this: ```crd['Trade Date - Settle Date'] =  df.apply(lambda row: np.busday_count(row['TRADE_DATE'], row['SETTLE_DATE'],holidays=holidaydates.Date[holidaydates.Currency.isin([row['TO_CRRNCY','FROM_CRRNCY']])]), axis=1)```

Comment: Furthermore, I received this error when trying to print the row ```print holidaydates.Date[holidaydates.Currency.isin([['TO_CRRNCY','FROM_CRRNCY']])]``` error:  ```Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)```. I've deleted the earlier performance analysis, as it turns out that the holiday calendars weren't being processed correctly, so that is moot.

Comment: `row['TO_CRRNCY', 'FROM_CRRNCY']` attempts to get the item with index `('TO_CRRNCY', 'FROM_CRRNCY')` (i.e. multi-index) from the row but it doesn't exist. You probably want `row['TO_CRRNCY'], row['FROM_CRRNCY']` instead.

Comment: Thanks - that's now giving an error about the dates being in the wrong format: ```ValueError: ('Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates', u'occurred at index 0')``` The holidaydates start as a ```dataframe``` shape (1464,2). Columns 'Currency' and 'Date'. When I forced an index to be the "Currency" value, this effectively ignored the contents. ```holidaydates = holidaydates.reindex(['Currency'])```

Comment: Could you post an update with example data and the specific code you used?

Comment: Full updated code has been provided - thanks again for the help here!

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) you need data type datetime64 not `str`. I.e. you should set column type to date time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188308/discussion-between-a-guest-and-hadynb).